# Google Chrome Extension: Toggling a Function

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, toggle

I'm just starting out with javascript.  My chrome extension is currently functioning but I'd like to add more functionality to it. When clicked, it runs this in background.html:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function (tab) {
chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, { file: "hello.js" });
});
```

If I wanted to have the button toggle between hello.js script and goodbye.js; how would I accomplish this?

Comment: Is there any reason why you don't just use one file and toggle in that?

Answer (score 0):

```
if (localStorage["toggle"] && localStorage["toggle"]=="hello"){
    alert("Good Bye");
    localStorage["toggle"]="goodbye";
} else {
    alert("Hello");
    localStorage["toggle"]="hello";
}
```

Thats how Id do it in the popup of a Browser Actions html/js.
If your doing it from the background then just change the localStorage to a variable.

```
var toggle;

chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function (tab) {

if (toggle=="hello"){
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, { file: "goodbye.js" });;
    toggle="goodbye";
} else {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, { file: "hello.js" });
    toggle="hello";
}

});
```